# OpenCV Python unable to open videofile

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I am using Windows 10 and the 2.7.12 32-bit version of Python and Opencv 3.1.0. Below is the code where it goes wrong:

```
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("StraightAhead.avi")
if not vcap.isOpened():
    print "File Cannot be Opened"
```

First off, all of this code works when using webcam (so `VideoCapture(0)`).

I have tried a couple of things. First off, it was originally an mp4 so I converted it to avi. I tried a file (.webm) from a friend who is using Linux with python and opencv which worked for him but not for me.

I checked to see if I could move the DLL files from opencv ffmpeg to Python but there are no DLL files for me there. I checked a lot of other questions but most of them give solutions for Linux.

The most relevant question doesn't have any answers or comments so I finally decided to ask it here. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score -1):

Tried your code and it works on my 64-bit Win10 machine. The file you need for 32-bit Windows is 'opencv_ffmpeg310.dll'. Suggest you download the binary from [OpenCV Download site](http://opencv.org/downloads.html), install it and try again. The ffmpeg DLL is located in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV 3.1.0\x64\vc14\bin'. Also need to add the paths below if the installer doesn't add them to the windows environment.

```
OPENCV_DIR='C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV 3.1.0\x64\vc14' 
PATH = %PATH%;%OPENCV_DIR%\bin
```

Note that vc14 is compiled by Visual Studio 2015 or vc12 by VS2013.

Hope this help.

Comment: So yes I did all this and when I reinstalled it said something like "output file opencv_ffmpeg.dll not placed" or something like that, I tried reinstalling again to recreate it but it instantly closed the install screen when done. I extracted with open as administrator. And also if the path wasn't set up correctly how could it work with cam then? 
The problem persists and my x64 folder isn't immediately in the top folder but in build. Also when I check the ffmpeg folder there is no DLL there

Comment: I reinstalled, added the path again and moved the ffmpeg DLL to the Python DLL folder. Still not working I also downloaded Visual Studio 15, but it worked with webcam before with a lot of opencv stuff so I am sure opencv works (I had a ball tracker working with the webcam)

Comment: @Marciano Firstly, suggest you to take a look [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) in order for the reader to understand your question.

Comment: Your comments seem leading to more confusions. Are you using 32-bit OpenCV in 32-bit Windows? Do you build and compile OpenCV 3.1 yourself or just download the binary and install or copy the files to the directory? **ffmpeg** is for video encoding or decoding. It doesn't directly deal with video stream playback from webcam. The webcam would work with OpenCV Video I/O module without opencv_ffmpeg.dll (32-bit) or opencv_ffmpeg_x64.dll (64-bit).

Comment: I apologise for the noncoherent question, I was trying to ask the question and simultaneously show that I did attempt to find an answer to the problem and not come across as lazy. For the specific project I am working on I need 32 bit compatibility so I picked 32 bit on all sources. Yes I use the self extracting download of OpenCV. Your comment on the webcam working makes sense. I think now it boils down to what step am I missing when trying to get a video file to run instead of webcam.

Comment: OK. Where did you download the binary, http://opencv.org/downloads.html? And which version?

Comment: After trying your steps it didn't work, changing the path to specifically point to the DLL file didn't work either. Still this if statement tells me "File cannot be opened"

Answer (score -1):

You may extact the binary to C:\ and try again.

1. Set OPENCV_DIR = C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14
   *{ opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll are there }*
2. Add PATH with %OPENCV_DIR%\bin
3. Copy C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x86\cv2.pyd to
   %PYTHON%\lib\site-packages\cv2.pyd *{ where %PYTHON% is the 32-bit
   python root directory, e.g. "C:\Program File (x86)\Python27" }*

If still doesn't work, change OpenCV path to use 32-bit version of ffmpeg DLL deliberately.

4. Set OPENCV_DIR to C:\opencv\build\ *{ to use 32-bit ffmpeg under bin\ }*

If problem still exists, log the Traceback message.

**EDIT:** Just tested the opencv-3.1.0.exe downloaded from opencv website. Video file playback, used 'Wildlife.wmv' comes with 32-bit Win7, works.

It looks that the EXE zipped with two set of files ... The OPENCV_DIR was set to C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc12. And copied c:\opencv\opencv\build\python\2.7\x86\cv2.pyd cv2.pyd to python's lib\site-packages. That's all.

Comment: What are the path setup for your OpenCV 3.1 and Python?

Comment: Okay first off thank you for taking the time to help me. I will here list the paths that I have and tried. For Python: C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts. And these are the paths I tried with the opencv C:\Program Files (x86)\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin didn't work and changed it to this -> C:\Program Files (x86)\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll. Still didn't work and the Trace back message is it prints that file cannot be opened, shows the module the error occurs and line number, followed by this:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: The environment variables OPENCV_DIR for your case should be just "C:\Program Files (x86)\opencv\build\x64\vc14\". PATH should include %OPENCV_DIR%\bin. Your case, it may search for the file under bin\opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll\. it looks that AttributeError is due to decode failed and unable to detect input video file type.

Comment: If I understand correctly I should set my opencv path variable to: C:\Program Files (x86)\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin , which I have done now. Could there be something wrong in my ffmpeg install then? Seeing as clearly opencv works?

Comment: You may try my one. It's from OpenCV communities when I build the OpenCV. It works very well no matter it's a binary or my own build.

Comment: @Marciano, see EDIT above.

Comment: For some reason when I unzip it it doesn't come with an x86 folder within build. There is however a bin folder within build that holds both the ffmpeg dll. Making the path point to this bin however also fails

Comment: What's the URL of your download

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.1.0/opencv-3.1.0.exe/download This is the one I used.

Comment: Then, what's your OPENCV_DIR setting? Did you also add path for %OPENCV_DIR%\bin where the ffmpeg DLL located?